# Relationship between Poisson generation and generalized Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, kullback-leibler, matrix-decomposition

I have read that, in the context of matrix factorization, performing maximum likelihood estimation under the assumption that the entries are Poisson generated is equivalent to minimizing the generalized Kullback-Leibler divergence between the matrix and the product of its factors.

Does anyone know how to show this?

(for an example of this claim, see, e.g. page 2 of Lee and Seung's [paper on NMF in Nature](http://hebb.mit.edu/people/seung/papers/ls-lponm-99.pdf).)

Comment: The link to the paper is dead, I'm guessing it it this one _Learning the parts of objects by non-negative matrix factorization_, Lee & Seung (1999) https://www.nature.com/articles/44565

Answer (score 4):

I worked it out in the end and I'll link to it here, in case someone else is interested.  I wrote it up here http://building-babylon.net/2015/02/17/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-non-negative-matrix-factorisation-and-the-generalised-kullback-leibler-divergence/

Comment: The link shows a Google Drive document that is not public. Could you make it have publica access, or better yet post the full derivation here?

Answer (score 4):

We want to proof that
\begin{align}
argmin_{W,H} \qquad D_{KL}(\boldsymbol{V} | \boldsymbol {WH})
\quad = \quad
argmax_{W,H} \qquad p(\boldsymbol{V} | \boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{H})
\end{align}
under a Poisson distribution.

The KL divergence (actually the I-divergence) is defined as
\begin{align}
D_{KL}(\boldsymbol{V} | \boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{H}) = \sum_f \sum_n 
\left[
v_{fn} 
\ln \frac{v_{fn}}{\sum_k w_{fk}h_{kn}} + \sum_k w_{fk}h_{kn} - v_{fn}
\right]
\end{align}
And the likelihood can be expressed in terms of the KL divergence:
\begin{align}
\ln p(\boldsymbol{V} | \boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{H})
&=
\sum_{f,n}
\ln
\left[
\exp\left\lbrace -\sum_k w_{fk}h_{kn}\right\rbrace
\frac{(\sum w_{fk}h_{kn})^{v_{fn}}}{v_{fn}!}
\right]
\\
&=
\sum_{f,n}
\left[
{v_{fn}} \ln\sum w_{fk}h_{kn}
-\sum_k w_{fk}h_{kn} - \ln v_{fn}!
\right]
\\
&=
\sum_{f,n}
\left[
{v_{fn}} \ln\frac{\sum w_{fk}h_{kn}}{v_{fn}}
-\sum_k w_{fk}h_{kn}
- \ln v_{fn}!
+v_{fn}\ln v_{fn}
\right]
\\
&=
-D_{KL}(\boldsymbol{V} | \boldsymbol{W}\boldsymbol{H}) - v_{fn} + 
\left[
v_{fn}\ln v_{fn}
- \ln v_{fn}!
\right]
\end{align}
Therefore, both the likelihood and the KL divergence have the same optimum with respect to $\boldsymbol{W}, \boldsymbol{H}$.